# Highlighting haskell listings in large *.tex document

Tags: beamer, listings, tex-core

Suppose, there is a large `*.tex` document, which has many nested `\input` directives with many Haskell listings surrounded by `\begin{code} \end{code}`
commands.

How can all this code listings be highlighted like all haskell code is highlighted in many haskell papers (functional pearls is a good example)?

I heard, that many haskell papers written in `lhs` and then transferred to `tex` via `lhs2tex`. Yep, this is a nice tool, but it produces whole `tex` document and it is hard to be usable for the task like mine.

---

Btw, I've tried `lstlistings` and `fancyvrb` - it's far away from ideal.

Comment: In what way is `lstlistings` insufficient?  I can't help if what I think is the right answer was already dismissed without explanation.

Comment: I guess what he means is that you do not get an ideal result by just using the package `lstlistings` (which is true in my experience). You have to spend some effort for the setup, then `lstlistings` is definitely the/a way to go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was pleased with my `lstlistings` setup which I used in my bachelor thesis:

```
\lstset{
  frame=none,
  xleftmargin=2pt,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=5pt,
  numberstyle=\ttfamily\tiny\color[gray]{0.3},
  belowcaptionskip=\bigskipamount,
  captionpos=b,
  escapeinside={*'}{'*},
  language=haskell,
  tabsize=2,
  emphstyle={\bf},
  commentstyle=\it,
  stringstyle=\mdseries\rmfamily,
  showspaces=false,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\rmfamily,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  showstringspaces=false,
  morecomment=[l]\%,
}
```

You can find some examples in my thesis: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zu56xcp1mj57ikq/TtFoHKmOLV/thesis.pdf

I can also provide the whole `.tex` source if needed.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Thanks for wanting to share your thesis with examples, but the link is broken.

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure what you mean by "many nested `\input` directives with many Haskell listings surrounded by `\begin{code} \end{code}` commands" but... the [`minted` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) supports Haskell syntax highlighting. Here is some sample code, taken from the [Wikipedia page on the Haskell programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{haskell}
-- Type annotation (optional)
fib :: Int -> Integer

-- With self-referencing data
fib n = fibs !! n
        where fibs = 0 : scanl (+) 1 fibs
        -- 0,1,1,2,3,5,...

-- Same, coded directly
fib n = fibs !! n
        where fibs = 0 : 1 : next fibs
              next (a : t@(b:_)) = (a+b) : next t

-- Similar idea, using zipWith
fib n = fibs !! n
        where fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)

-- Using a generator function
fib n = fibs (0,1) !! n
        where fibs (a,b) = a : fibs (b,a+b)
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is showing me this error
```line 3: Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag. \begin
line 3: Emergency stop. \begin{document}
: shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.
```