# Markup Haskell sources in complex structured document with `lhs2TeX`

Tags: listings, highlighting, lhs2tex

## Simple task

Suppose there is a `example.tex` file with Haskell listings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{code}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small}

\begin{document}
\begin{code}
sequence :: [IO a] -> IO [a]
sequence      [] = return []
sequnce (c : cs) = do
  x <- c
  xs <- sequence cs
  return (x : xs)
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

[image: easy before]

Let's prepare this file to be processed via `lhs2TeX`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%include lhs2TeX.fmt
%include lhs2TeX.sty

\begin{document}
\begin{code}
sequence :: [IO a] -> IO [a]
sequence      [] = return []
sequnce (c : cs) = do
  x <- c
  xs <- sequence cs
  return (x : xs)
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

- `lhs2TeX example.tex -o example_new.tex`
- `pdflatex example_new.tex`

What we've got:

[image: easy after]

It is exactly how I want sources to look like.

## Real-world example

In real world there are often many files with haskell sources collected by `\input` command in main file:

`hardmod.tex`:

```
\documentclass{disser}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{code}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small}
\begin{document}
\input{first}
\input{second}
\end{document}
```

`first.tex`:

```
Some stuff

\begin{code}
sequence :: [IO a] -> IO [a]
sequence      [] = return []
sequnce (c : cs) = do
  x <- c
  xs <- sequence cs
  return (x : xs)
\end{code}

and more words.
```

`second.tex`:

```
Another example of code:
\begin{code}
ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
ap mf mx = do
  f <- mf
  x <- mx
  return (f x)
\end{code}
And a conclusion.
```

`lhs2TeX` produces whole latex document, that why it is kinda tricky to compile `hardmod.tex` with nice sources prepared by `lhs2TeX`.

**Question**: how can `lhs2TeX` could be used in complex structured document like this to get nice source formatting?

Comment: It seems to me that this question is a better explained version of [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116595/highlighting-haskell-listings-in-large-tex-document)? Should we close the latter as a duplicate?

Comment: I thought that it will be a bad idea to edit question you mentioned after two days, that why I've tried to create another one with better explanations. Yep, question #116595 could be closed.

Comment: I understand you want to typeset your Haskell code with syntax highlighting. I'm more familiar with `minted` than I am with `lhs2TeX`, which seems to be specific to Haskell. Do you absolutely want to use `lhs2TeX` or are you open to a `minted` solution?

Comment: `lhs2TeX` is preferred because of `--math` and `--poly` formatting.

Comment: Question: Why do you have Haskell listings in .tex files? Wouldn't it be easier to keep them in their original .lhs files and import them in your hardmod.tex file with a dedicated package such as `listings` or `minted`?

Comment: Imaging `first.tex` and `second.tex` as a large files with ~500 lines and only 100 of them is source code.

Comment: I've just found the [`docmute`](http://ctan.org/pkg/docmute) package which redefines the `\input` command to completely ignore the preamble or the inputted document. This is a minimalistic package and you should also check out `standalone` or `subfiles`.

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ I've closed the older one, although to be honest two days doesn't seem too long to me :-)

Comment: ignoring preamble doesn't work, because `tex` file generated from `lhs` contains a lot of definition in own preamble.

Answer (score 3):

#### Actual answer

You have two options:

1. Use `lhs2TeX`'s `%include` directive rather than `\input`. This is the easiest way, and I'd recommend it.
2. Process each file separately using `lhs2TeX` and then combine the results. Each file has to have an `%include polycode.fmt` line then. This option can be useful if you need very different formatting directives for different parts of your code (for example if you use `lhs2TeX` to process a different programming language).

Note that your question is actually the topmost FAQ in the [lhs2TeX manual](http://www.andres-loeh.de/lhs2tex/Guide2-1.17.pdf).

#### Some additional remarks

1. You should put your sources in `.lhs` files, not `.tex` files. It's the whole point of `lhs2TeX` that you have literate Haskell sources, and they're still valid Haskell.
2. You should not use

   ```
   %include lhs2TeX.fmt
   %include lhs2TeX.sty
   ```

   This is long deprecated. Instead, use

   ```
   %include polycode.fmt
   ```
3. You are saying that your example looks exactly like you want typeset Haskell code to look, but actually, you are not making use of `lhs2TeX`'s alignment features, which is one of the main advantages of using it. To get the `=` symbols aligned in the output, make sure that you have two spaces in front of them in the source.